# Clear Text boxes within a Multipage Control on Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a school project while learning vba for the first time. The project is built around a wedding planning worksheet. I plan to lockdown the worksheet so that formulas and formatting don't get broken by the user (my fiance would find a way). In order to do this, I am building a userform that collects the data via text boxes on different pages of a multipage control.

This example only has one page, but it will show others like "Apparel" later:
[image]

I currently have the following code on _Click for the "Clear" button.

```
Dim C As Control


For Each C In frmExpenses.Controls
    If TypeName(C) = "TextBox" Then
        C.Value = ""
    End If
Next C
```

This effectively clears the data from the text boxes. However, I want to be able to clear the data on ONLY the active page on the multipage. For example if there is later a tab called "Flowers" and it's the active tab, I want to leave the data on "Apparel" and clear the data from "Flowers."

I tried being as thorough as possible above. Let me know, if you need clarification on something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

**For a particular Page (Say 1)**

```
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(1).Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then  ctl.Value = ""
Next
```

**From ActivePage**

```
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Value).Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then ctl.Value = ""
Next
```

Comment: It doesn't like:

    Pages(Me.MultiPage1.Value)

Specifically, the debugger highlights the "MultiPage1" part.

I tried correcting that part to the the name I had given the multipage but it didn't correct the issue either.

Comment: I tested it before posting :) Let me think what could be the problem at your end...

Comment: Nevermind, in my original question I didn't indicate that I actually had a warning userform initiate on _Click of "Cancel". This caused "Me" not to work. I changed that to the original userform and it worked perfectly.

Thanks a ton!